# Parsing a structure in C++ and searching for a value in it

Tags: c++, structure

Hi I am working on class work and I am writing a function that shows the highest points as well as the player name that scored the highest points.

Here is what I have so far It works mostly but loops back and begins to print the next name in array. I tried using a while loop but could not get it to work correctly. Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help.

```
double temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (player[i].pointsScored > temp)
    {
        temp = player[i].pointsScored;
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << player[i].playerName << ' ';

    if (temp == player[i].pointsScored)
    {
        cout << "scored the highest points with " << temp << " points";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the second loop you *always* print the names, of all "players", unconditionally.

Comment: What's wrong with the output apart from printing everything on one line? You programmed it to print every name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is what I have so far It works mostly but loops back and begins to print the next name in array.

To avoid this, break from the loop once you find the player with the highest score. Also, you don't need to print the names of all the players while you search for the player with the highest score. Move the line that prints the player's name inside the `if` block.

```
double temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   if (player[i].pointsScored > temp)
   {
      temp = player[i].pointsScored;
   }
}


for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   cout << player[i].playerName << ' ';

   if (temp == player[i].pointsScored)
   {
      cout
         << player[i].playerName << ' '
         << "scored the highest points with " << temp << " points";

      // No need to loop any more.
      // Break out of the loop.
      break;
   }
}
```

You can also store the index of the player with the highest score and just print the info of that player.

```
int highestScoreIndex = 0;
double temp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   if (player[i].pointsScored > temp)
   {
      temp = player[i].pointsScored;
      highestScoreIndex = i;
   }
}

cout
   << player[highestScoreIndex].playerName << ' '
   << "scored the highest points with " << temp << " points";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel stupid now probably the serious sleep deprivation that I am enjoying thanks to finals.

Answer (score 1):

> Don't use another loop to get the name of the player, get it in the
>   first loop itself.

```
double temp = 0;
String name="";
for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE-1; i++)
{

    if (player[i].pointsScored > temp)
    {
        temp = player[i].pointsScored;
        name = player[i].playerName;
    } 

}
cout << name <<" scored the highest points with " << temp << " points";
```

**Alternate:**(This better as it uses lesser space & is faster)

```
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
{

    if (player[i].pointsScored > player[temp].pointsScored)
    {
        temp =i;
    } 

}
cout << player[temp].playerName<<" scored the highest points with " << player[temp].pointsScored << " points";
```

Comment: Storing index or `Player` is simpler. Also show the output statement.

Comment: @LogicStuff Alternative method put up.

Comment: You need `player[i].pointsScored > player[temp].pointsScored` and start from `i = 1`. Also fix the formatting and I'll give you +1.

Comment: @LogicStuff made it a loop from 0 to size-1 and thanks for the correction.

Comment: No, you want to skip the first element because `temp` starts with `0`, not the last.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109871/discussion-between-ani-menon-and-logicstuff).

Answer (score 0):

you should make changes in second loop where you are printing the name and the score..

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{



    if (temp == player[i].pointsScored)
    {
        cout << player[i].playerName << " ";

        cout << "scored the highest points with " << temp << " points";
        break;
    }


}
```

and The second solution is..

```
double temp = 0;
string tempPlayerName="";

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{

       if (player[i].pointsScored > temp)
       {

    temp = player[i].pointsScored;
    tempPlayerName=player[i].playerName;
}
}
cout<<"Player Name who has scored highest points "<<tempPlayerName;
cout<<" and points are  "<<temp;
```